# Convert a byte string to hexadecimal string in python

Tags: python, encoding, type-conversion, sha256, aws-signature

I'm working on a project with heavy usage of AWS Signature. Now my task is to find a way to send an SHA256-hashed byte "string" to a client via JSON. The given "string" looks like this:

```
b'\xd2\x99Q\xb5^\x89\x99\xc3\xa7\\\x98.\x00\x87\xaf`|E\xd2\xc9:B)\xc5\xfe\x869X\xd1\xc5K\xb4'
```

Yes, I am using python. That "string" is a product of encoding a byte string to utf-8, then hash it using SHA256. I don't even know how to call it, but I need to somehow convert it to a normal string, so I can dump it into JSON. After conversion it should look like this:

```
d7fd3471194dedeafcb7b5ca17daa05e01ffcafa41227fa7d3d82ec0bdeacc8f
```

Note that the above string is not the result of conversion, I just attached it so you guys can understand the issue better.

I have tried encoding it with base64, but I cannot decode it afterwards. To put things simply I am pretty stuck here. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, SHA256 hashing cannot be converted back (at least trivially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method:

```
>>> s = b'\xd2\x99Q\xb5^\x89\x99\xc3\xa7\\\x98.\x00\x87\xaf`|E\xd2\xc9:B)\xc5\xfe\x869X\xd1\xc5K\xb4'
>>> s.hex()
'd29951b55e8999c3a75c982e0087af607c45d2c93a4229c5fe863958d1c54bb4'
```

Comment: Oh God you did it! I’ve been at this a few nights and couldn’t even know what it’s called! Thank you.